# How to sum 2-dimensional arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby, matrix, sketchup

I have a two-dimensional array with sub-arrays of equal size, for example:

```
array = [
  [10, 12, 15 ,17], [16, 32, 65, 47], [45, 48, 41, 23],
  [36, 25, 74, 98], [32, 19, 66, 88]
]
```

I would like to create a new array by summing the corresponding elements of every 4th sub-array, i.e. the elements that are "on top of each other" in the above example:

```
new_array = [
  [10 + 36, 12 + 25, 15 + 74, 17 + 98],
  [16 + 32, 32 + 19, 65 + 66, 47 + 88],
  [45, 48, 4‌​1, 23]
]
```

These are just examples, the actual arrays can be larger.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you want to achieve? Are you trying to sum the rows or columns of the matrix?

Comment: Please provide a clear explanation as to how you want sum to happen on 2d array.

Comment: new_array = [[10+36+..,12+25+...,15+74+...,17+98+...],[16+32+...,32+19+...,65+66+...,47+88+...],[45+...,48+...,41+..,23+...]]

Comment: result should look like this 3x4

Comment: The dots means that the arrays continues

Comment: Please provide a complete array as input (no `...`), and a complete example as output.

Comment: **After all, what is your question?**

Comment: it can be unlimited

Comment: Obviously, an array could have any size. You could still show an example with 12 subarrays, and show what the result should be. If it works with 12 arrays, the solution will also probably work with N arrays.

Comment: array = [[10,12,15,17],[19,32,65,47],[45,48,41,23],[36,25,74,98],[10,12,15,17],[16,98,65,47],[69,48,65,23],[66,25,74,98]]

Comment: result new_array = [[115,85,154,138],[95,69,154,162],[61,146,106,70]]

Comment: `array` has 8 sub-arrays. How do you manage to get 3 subarrays after transposition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Complete Matrix

You can use [`each_slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice), [`transpose`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-transpose), [`map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-map) and [`transpose`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-transpose) again to navigate your matrix.
The code first uses `join('+')` to show what is being calculated :

```
array= [[10,12,15,17],[16,32,65,47],[45,48,41,23],[36,25,74,98],[32,19,66,88],[1,2,3,4]]

array.each_slice(3).to_a.transpose.map{|r| r.transpose.map{|x| x.join('+')}}
# => [["10+36", "12+25", "15+74", "17+98"], ["16+32", "32+19", "65+66", "47+88"], ["45+1", "48+2", "41+3", "23+4"]]

array.each_slice(3).to_a.transpose.map{|r| r.transpose.map{|x| x.inject(:+)}}
# => [[46, 37, 89, 115], [48, 51, 131, 135], [46, 50, 44, 27]]
```

Warning!

You need to carefully select the `each_slice` parameter to suit your original array. `transpose` might raise an exception otherwise :

```
array = [[10,12,15,17],[19,32,65,47],[45,48,41,23],[36,25,74,98],[10,12,15,17],[16,98,65,47],[69,48,65,23],[66,25,74,98]]
array.each_slice(3).to_a.transpose.map{|r| r.transpose.map{|x| x.inject(:+)}}
#=> IndexError: element size differs (2 should be 3)
array.each_slice(4).to_a.transpose.map{|r| r.transpose.map{|x| x.inject(:+)}}
#=> [[20, 24, 30, 34], [35, 130, 130, 94], [114, 96, 106, 46], [102, 50, 148, 196]]
```

## Incomplete Matrix

If the matrix `size` isn't a multiple of `width` :

```
array = [
  [10, 12, 15 ,17], [16, 32, 65, 47], [45, 48, 41, 23],
  [36, 25, 74, 98], [32, 19, 66, 88]
]
```

you could add subarrays full of 0s to get :

```
matrix = [
  [10, 12, 15 ,17], [16, 32, 65, 47], [45, 48, 41, 23],
  [36, 25, 74, 98], [32, 19, 66, 88], [ 0,  0,  0,  0]
]
```

[Array#fill](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-fill) does the job :

```
def maxtrix_column_sums(array, width)
  size    = array.size
  size2   = array.first.size
  missing = (-size) % width
  matrix  = array.dup.fill(Array.new(size2, 0), size...size + missing)
  matrix.each_slice(width).to_a.transpose.map { |r| r.transpose.map { |x| x.join('+') } }
end

p maxtrix_column_sums(array, 3)
#=> [["10+36", "12+25", "15+74", "17+98"], ["16+32", "32+19", "65+66", "47+88"], ["45+0", "48+0", "41+0", "23+0"]]
```

Comment: You're welcome. You'll get better at asking question with time ;)

Comment: You can use `zip` instead of `transpose` to combine arrays of different sizes, although the code would need some adjustments in that case.

Comment: Yes. It wasn't clear if the OP allows incomplete matrices. I'll update the code

Answer (score 0):

Here's a variation of [Eric Duminil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41506114/477037) using `zip` instead of `transpose` to account for an "odd" number of sub-arrays:

```
first, *rest = array.each_slice(3).to_a
first.zip(*rest).map { |r| r.compact.transpose.map { |x| x.inject(:+) } }
#=> [[46, 37, 89, 115], [48, 51, 131, 135], [45, 48, 41, 23]]
```

How it works:

`each_slice` separates the array into groups of 3:

```
array.each_slice(3).to_a
#=> [
#     [[10, 12, 15, 17], [16, 32, 65, 47], [45, 48, 41, 23]],
#     [[36, 25, 74, 98], [32, 19, 66, 88]]
#   ]
```

`first.zip(*rest)` combines the first slice "column"-wise with the remaining slices, adding `nil` when a slice is missing:

```
first.zip(*rest)
#=> [
#     [[10, 12, 15, 17], [36, 25, 74, 98]],
#     [[16, 32, 65, 47], [32, 19, 66, 88]],
#     [[45, 48, 41, 23], nil]
#   ]
```

The `map` / `compact` / `transpose` part then restructures the sub-array while getting rid of `nil` values:

```
first.zip(*rest).map { |r| r.compact.transpose }
#=> [
#     [[10, 36], [12, 25], [15, 74], [17, 98]],
#     [[16, 32], [32, 19], [65, 66], [47, 88]],
#     [[45],     [48],     [41],     [23]]
#   ]
```

And `inject(:+)` finally sums the inner elements.